# Angular2 adding attribute to element

Tags: angular

How do I add an attribute to an element when it is created ?

I tried the following Dashboard component:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Renderer  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '[re-dashboard]',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent {

  constructor (private _el: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer) {
    _renderer.setElementAttribute(_el, 're-component','');
  }
}
```

I would like to add `re-component` attribute to the div when the DashboardComponent is being created. I then use `re-component` to style the created div. However I get the following error: http://pastebin.com/up35zmUv

Any ideas

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Component({
  selector: '[re-dashboard]',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss'],
  host: {
      "re-component": "",
  }
})
export class DashboardComponent {}
```

Comment: This works by adding a class. Good. However I am now more interested in  a way to do this with code and to add an attribute ?

Comment: EDIT - this is what I want. Sry. I have understood the documentation wrong

Comment: You`r welcome! Don´t forget to pick the answer as "accepted answer" to complete this issue.