# How do I add an attribute to a dynamically created element in Angular2+?

Tags: javascript, angular, attributes, addition, angular-renderer2

I have had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261962/how-to-set-attributes-on-an-element-in-angular-2) but it does not work -- maybe because the elements I am targeting are dynamically generated inside a custom component (`<c-tabs>`).

I have also had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40806407/angular2-adding-attribute-to-element) but this wouldn't work, I think, as i am not able to touch the custom component's code.

***Relevant Elements***
[image]

***HTML***

```
<c-tabs #mainComponentTabs1 [items]="tabItems"></c-tabs>
```

I have tried the following ways to target it. None works.

***Method 1. Using plain old Javascript:***

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    let att = document.createAttribute("id");
    att.value = "yada1";
    document.querySelectorAll(".c-tabs .hydrated")[0].setAttributeNode(att);
}
```

I have tried to have the above in the ngOnInit and ngOnViewInit methods but that didn't help.
**This method, oddly enough, works in the Chrome console window after the page has rendered.** That is, the querySelected items get id attribute.

***Method2. Using Angular's Renderer2***. (Admittedly, I don't know how to get to the particular native elements that need the id's.

```
//first, declare target custom component element with viewchild:
export class MainComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked, AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('mainComponentTabs1', { static: true }) c_tabs1: ElementRef;
    ...
    ngAfterViewChecked() {
        //neither of these approaches works.
        const c_tabs1El = this.c_tabs1.nativeElement;    
        this.renderer.setAttribute(c_tabs1El.items[0], 'id', 'dashboard-tab-link-search');

        const c_tabs1El2 = document.querySelectorAll("button.c-item");
        this.renderer.setAttribute(c_tabs1El2[0].nativeElement, 'id', 'dashboard-tab-link-dashboard');
      }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what elements are you trying to target, if you're trying to target the elements by class or tag but I think the following code will help you:

```js
export class MainComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked, AfterViewInit {
    // the static property must be true only if you are using it in ngOnInit
    @ViewChild('mainComponentTabs1', { static: false }) c_tabs1: ElementRef;
    ...
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        const targetElements = this.c_tabs1.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('button.c-item')

        targetELements.forEach((el, index) => this.renderer.setAttribute(el, 'id', `dashboard-tab-link-search-${index}`));
      }
    ...
}
```

Don't touch the DOM directly.

Comment: this worked -- but only when i put this code in the ngAfterViewChecked() life-cycle method! TY!

Comment: @inonut-t Is there any good reason to use a local reference and ViewChild if we can target an element reliably with document.querySelector/All ?

Comment: @PakiPat using `Document` is not considered a good practice because are cases where no browser is available (for example doing server side rendering with Universal). The ElementRef and Renderer2 provides an abstraction for this kind of cases.